# Placing a png image in a table

Tags: html, css

Hi I know this is a simple question. But I am unable to do it. I want to place images in a table. Everything is working fine in a new html file. But when I am trying to insert the table in my project file, the images are getting overlapped.They are not fitting in a table. What mistake am I doing? Kindly look at the image that is attached.

```css
table,td,th {border: 3px solid black;padding: 15px}
```

```html
<table>
      <tr><th>Choose from the icons</th></tr>
      <tr><td ><img src='http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/smiley-icon-1.png' width='20%'/></td></tr>
      <tr><td ><img src='http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/smiley-icon-1.png'width=20%/></td></tr>

    </table>
```

[image]

Comment: What is the code for your project file?

Comment: can you  use a jsfiddle?

Comment: I am trying to make a matching game where the users can choose a icon and the matching game starts with the selected icon. I want to list all icons in a table. But I don't know why its not working. @JesseElser

Comment: Can you be a little clearer? Sorry I am new to html and css so can you please expand the use of jsfiddle? @ShankarShastri

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. I suspect that your [mcve] is incomplete and is missing some code related to absolute positioning

Comment: Thank you @Quentin. The problem occured because I used 'position:absolute' in my program. When I removed it the images are going inside the table. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```css
table,
td,
th {
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 15px
}
img.icon {
  width: 20%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Choose from the icons</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src='heart1.png' class="icon" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src='heart1.png' class="icon" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept an answer to close this question if the solution worked.

Comment: Also , how can I pass the value to a function using onclick?  My lines are:   <tr><td><img src='heart1.png'  value= 'heart' onclick="selection(this.value)></td></tr>. My function is        function selection(a){ alert('selected' + a);}          Iam getting alert as ' selected undefined'. How can I display the value instead of undefined?

Answer (score 0):

this may works. if you have any query, you can comment and ask further.
this solution fix your image inside `<td>`

```css
table,
td,
th {
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 15px
}
td img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Choose from the icons</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src='heart1.png' class="icon" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src='heart1.png' class="icon" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @chirag, can't put as fiddle because i do not have a image.

Comment: if this answer helpful to you @Manikumar Perla, you can tick the answer and accept it.

Answer (score -1):

First you should always specify both height and width.

Second you should specify the width in pixels. AFAIK, the image tag does not support percentages.

[IMG tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_width.asp)

Third, your second image does not have quotes around the width value.

Ideally you should resize the image to work without a width and height defined.

The best way might be to set the image as the background image of the cell.

Comment: Thanks. Width in percentages is working fine with my code. I have edited my code and placed quotes for the value of the width. I want the user to select the icon, so by placing it in the background restricts the selection. So how can I do it?. @erols